# Hyper-v: unable to create new virtual machines

Tags: permissions, hyper-v

As recently as Tuesday I've been able to create virtual machines using Microsoft Hyper-V virtualalization software and thus far I've created 3.
All running Win2K12 server with SQL Server as a lab environment for setting up mirroring and replication (all through a legally obtained license, as part of the MS partner program).

The specs of my work laptop are:

- Windows 10 Pro
- 16 gigs of ram
- i7-6700HQ @2.60GHz
- NVidia GTX 960M

As of yesterday I was not able to create any new virtual machines, with the following [image]

I find this very strange: I've nog been fumbling with rights and/or permissions on my machine.

My troubleshooting log:

- A quick check in the local policies tells me the Administrators still have
   local log on rights,
- Turning all the existing virtual machines of doesn't help,
- Windows Defender and Hitman Pro can't find any abnormalities,
- Rebooting doesn't help ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"This issue occurs because the NT Virtual Machine\Virtual Machines special identity does not have the Log on as a Service right on the Hyper-V host computer. Usually, the Virtual Machine Management Service (VMMS) replaces this user permission at every Group Policy refresh to ensure it is always present. However, you may notice that Group Policy refresh does not function correctly in certain situations. "

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2779204

Solution in CMD:

```
gpupdate /force
```

Comment: Fixed my issue, never seen this before today, thanks!